# Firefox Extension Popup Background Colour

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I am looking to change the colour of the triangle that pops up when the popup from Firefox/Chrome extensions is shown, does anyone know how to do this?

[image: White Triangle Popup]

Comment: Chrome doesn't show it anymore. In Firefox it's copied from background-color for `body`.

Comment: In regard to Firefox copying it from the background-color of `body`, I don't see this behaviour either by setting the CSS style of `body` or the `bgcolor` attribute. Can you provide an example of this working?

Comment: Use a css file and `body { background: red }` inside.

Comment: Done but I am not seeing anything other than a white background, I can confirm via the inspector that the body's background is set correctly.